# Construct power series with domain of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the ball $$B = \{ \left| z_1 \right|^2 + \left| z_2 \right|^2 <1 \} \subset \mathbb{C}^2.$$ I want to construct a power series with domain of convergence $B$. My thoughts so far have been to consider a function of the form $$\frac{z_1 z_2}{1 - z_1^2 - z_2^2} = \sum_{\mu = 0}^{\infty} (z_1z_2(z_1^2-z_2^2))^{\mu}.$$ But I don't think this is correct.

Comment: Why not add two series one in $z_1$ and the other in $z_2$ with the relevant ROC?

Comment: @copper.hat Forgive me, I wrote the incorrect ROC. Please see edit.

Comment: Your example converges whenever $z_1=\pm z_2$ regardless of  the value of  $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2.$